# polars dataframe manipulation in python

Tags: dataframe, python-polars

I have a 455 x 147201 polars dataframe. 147000 columns of data are named data_1, ..., data_147000, and one column named 'radial'. I would like to:

1. identify rows that have the same 'radial' value. Potentially use partition_by() the 'radial' column?)
2. take average the data in those rows, so that i am left with one row. More specifically for the averaging, I want to take the average down each column of values so that I am left with one value at each column index.
3. recombine/output a polars dataframe that is still 147201 columns wide, but now has either the same or fewer rows than before the averaging process.

I do not have much experience using the polars library, and am hoping to save a few hours of playing around if anyone has a suggestion on which functions I could use to perform this operation?

Thank you!

I know that partition_by() can be used to create a list of dataframes containing only rows corresponding to a specific radial value. How to then average them? How to recombine the averaged rows?

Comment: Does "identify rows that have the same 'radial' value." mean the same as each other or as other columns?

Comment: From the next steps I think you mean as each other.

Answer (score 2):

Say you start with

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

df = (
    pl.DataFrame({'radial':np.random.choice(9,455)})
    .with_columns(**{f"data_{x}":pl.Series(
        np.random.normal(2,3,455))
        for x in range(1,14701)
                     })
    .sort('radial')
)
```

Then to get what you're after, you can just do

```
df.group_by('radial').agg(pl.all().mean())
```

if you want the `radial`s to stay in the same order then do

```
df.group_by('radial', maintain_order=True).agg(pl.all().mean())
shape: (9, 14_701)
┌────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬───┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┐
│ radial ┆ data_1   ┆ data_2   ┆ data_3   ┆ … ┆ data_14697 ┆ data_14698 ┆ data_14699 ┆ data_14700 │
│ ---    ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆   ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---        │
│ i64    ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆   ┆ f64        ┆ f64        ┆ f64        ┆ f64        │
╞════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪═══╪════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪════════════╡
│ 0      ┆ 2.364414 ┆ 2.57735  ┆ 1.898481 ┆ … ┆ 2.504495   ┆ 2.149989   ┆ 2.150744   ┆ 1.978022   │
│ 1      ┆ 1.41706  ┆ 1.604678 ┆ 1.991645 ┆ … ┆ 1.998777   ┆ 2.065698   ┆ 2.664061   ┆ 1.367012   │
│ 2      ┆ 1.992541 ┆ 1.691219 ┆ 2.550847 ┆ … ┆ 1.906468   ┆ 1.84318    ┆ 2.477806   ┆ 1.955094   │
│ 3      ┆ 2.367808 ┆ 1.235747 ┆ 2.378198 ┆ … ┆ 2.078475   ┆ 1.880346   ┆ 2.435088   ┆ 1.797085   │
│ 4      ┆ 0.734348 ┆ 2.193751 ┆ 2.280558 ┆ … ┆ 1.714504   ┆ 1.579873   ┆ 1.858307   ┆ 1.476204   │
│ 5      ┆ 2.904389 ┆ 2.291663 ┆ 1.050375 ┆ … ┆ 1.708348   ┆ 0.996591   ┆ 1.257452   ┆ 2.386301   │
│ 6      ┆ 1.736919 ┆ 2.301367 ┆ 1.820375 ┆ … ┆ 2.507111   ┆ 1.640286   ┆ 1.500142   ┆ 2.017649   │
│ 7      ┆ 2.287575 ┆ 1.925387 ┆ 2.625067 ┆ … ┆ 1.794704   ┆ 1.935146   ┆ 1.61927    ┆ 2.128247   │
│ 8      ┆ 1.553631 ┆ 1.420435 ┆ 2.226262 ┆ … ┆ 2.694876   ┆ 1.549308   ┆ 1.743394   ┆ 2.417845   │
└────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴───┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┘
```

As an aside, `partition_by` is really more for niche uses. The problem you described is a very *very* cookie cutter example of a `group_by.agg`